# Adding Pageable to my page using Spring boot

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add Pageable to my project using Spring-boot. I'm just learning Spring and I came across some tutorials but I didn't know how to implement it in my code. I would like to have 5 users displayed in every page. Clicking on buttons I would go trough batches of 5 displayed users.

Here is my code:
**UserRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

    Page<User> findUsersByPage(Pageable pageable);

}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usersList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userRepository.findAll());
        return "usersList";
    }
```

Also I have this pagination code from bootstrap

**index.html**

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" aria-
     label="Previous"> <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a></li>
   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next"> 
   <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a></li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Spring HATEOS and you are going to need some sort of (AJAX) query to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago I did something similar. When I scroll to the bottom of the page I load next 6 blog posts.

**PostRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY p.date DESC")
    List<Post> findLatestFromPage(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Making services is good practice because it makes controllers independent of repositories:

**PostService.java**

```
public interface PostService {

    List<Post> findLatest6FromPage(int page);
}
```

**PostServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    private final PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PostServiceImpl(PostRepository postRepository) {
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Post> findLatest6FromPage(int page) {
        return postRepository.findLatestFromPage(new PageRequest(page, 6));
    }
}
```

**PostController.java**

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/api/posts")
public class PostController {

    private final PostService postService;

    @Autowired
    public PostController(PostService postService) {
        this.postService = postService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/latest6FromPage")
    public List<Post> getLatest6PostsFromPage(@RequestParam("page") int page) {
        return postService.findLatest6FromPage(page);
    }
}
```

And I call the url to get 6 posts from page 2:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/posts/latest6FromPage?page=1
```

My controller is RestController so I use URL to get json with posts, but if you want to pass the users list directly to HTML file your controller might look like this:

```
@Controller
public class PostsController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @RequestMapping("/postList")
    public String postList(@RequestParam("page") int page, Model model) {
        List<Post> posts = postService.findLatest6FromPage(page);

        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
        return "postList";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I was useful! @M.Stefanczuk

Comment: @dome I'm glad to help you :) Please sign this answer as solution so others can find it easier.